# Значок Main camera в Unity

Tags: unity3d, 2d, камера, main

Ребят всем привет кто может сказать как убрать значок Main camera так сказать спрятать это он в центре и попадает на другие объекты никак не могу спрятать.

Answer (score 1):

Сверху на окне Scene кнопка Gizmos.
Она отвечает за отрисовку окна сцены.
Первый параметр - 3D Icons. Выкрутите слайдер на ноль и значка камеры не будет.

Comment: Cпасибо большое а если вовсе убрать 3D Icons?

Comment: @LCN_John Извините, что нескоро отвечаю. Если вы снимите галочку с 3DIcons значок камеры не пропадет. Я не совсем знаю почему. Но вам-то надо, чтобы она пропал, так что просто выкрутите на ноль. Если ответ был вам полезен, не забывайте принимать его кликом на галочку слева